# Spring integration dsl outboundGateway set query parameter using expression

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a rest request in spring integration flow. How to pick the value from the payload or header from message and set the query parameter of url

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway(UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("localhost:8080).path("search").queryParam("order", "orderId").toUriString())
.httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
.expectedResponseType(Order.class))
```

In the above code, i need to fetch the orderId from payload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist to use `UriComponentsBuilder`, then something like this:

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway(m ->
        UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("localhost:8080")
                    .path("search")
                    .queryParam("order", m.getPayload())
                    .build())
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .expectedResponseType(Order.class))
```

Or like this:

```
.handle(Http.outboundGateway(m -> servieUrl + "/search?orderId={orderId}")
            .uriVariable("orderId", m -> m.getPayload())
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .expectedResponseType(Order.class))
```

Comment: the above solution worked, is there any neat way of doing this in different way

Comment: Don't use `UriComponentsBuilder`, but just simple `String` for the uri and there is `uriVariable()` in the `Http.outboundGateway()` builder to enhance target uri with variables. I think we need to improve HTTP chapter in Reference Manual to include a Java DSL sample. Feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter

Comment: If i have use the uriVariable then the full url should be written which looks like `Http.outboundGateway("localhost:8080/search?orderId={orderId}").uriVariable("orderId", m -> m.getPayload())`

Comment: Correct. Is it bad?

Comment: "localhost:8080" is coming from property file, and its been used at multiple places, i should be careful while constructing url like `servieUrl + "/search?orderId={orderId}"` otherwise looks cool

Comment: See another sample in my answer.

Comment: but in my case `orderId` is not in header its in `payload`

Comment: OK. Fixed that in the answer. Although that's already not relevant to the question and suggested approach. More over you say in the question: ` from the payload or header from message`

Comment: Thanks for solution